# Getting strange magnetometerData in iPhone when programming iOS app with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, magnetometer

I am programming an iOS app which reads the data from magnetometer. When I run the app on two iPhones, they are creating strange data.

(All data are in [x, y, z] notation) An iPhone 5S creates about [100, 10, -100] and another iPhone 6S creates about [150, 225, -700]. The values shift about 10% when reading multiple times and holding the phone still, and they change little when I turn them.

However, the real magnetic field should be about [0, -30, -30] (measured by an app)

Why am I getting these strange data? (I also measured data from accelerometer, and the data are correct)

Here is my project's source code: https://github.com/lxylxy123456/FGFS-Controller/

What I did is basically like this

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.startMagnetometerUpdates()
if let magnetometerData = motionManager.magnetometerData {
    mx = magnetometerData.magneticField.x
    my = magnetometerData.magneticField.y
    mz = magnetometerData.magneticField.z
}
Mx.text = Float(mx).description
My.text = Float(my).description
Mz.text = Float(mz).description
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but don't use `Float.description` to display floating point numbers on labels. Just use String interpolation. `my.text = "\(mx)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `magnetometerData` is raw data, uncalibrated for internal bias as well as externalities (aka metal), and is essentially meaningless. There is no merit in using the raw data. There is basically *never* a reason to use these values.

Use the CMDeviceMotion's `magneticField` at the very least. Even better, ask for information that is germane to your real needs. If you want to know the device's heading, ask for that. If you want to know the device's orientation with reference to magnetic north, ask for that.

Comment: The idea seems to work, but I still have trouble getting correct `magneticField` (which always returns `[0, 0, 0]`) and `heading` (which is always a constant) from `CMDeviceMotion`. Using Core Location's heading solved my problem

Comment: CMDeviceMotion heading requires a northern frame of reference.